# find white space between characters php

Tags: php, trim

How can I trim white space between two specific characters in the same string? i.e. I just want to close the space between the first tag there and the start of the next word...

I want to turn this:

```
<code>

                                testing testing 123
test
```

into this:

```
<code>testing testing 123

test
```

The `<code>` will always be there, so perhaps I could use that as some sort of anchor point?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$trimmed = trim(substr($in, 6));
```

that will remove the whitespace after `<code>` up to the first non-whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `<code>` always exists at the beginning of your string, you can use:

```
$str = preg_replace( '/^<code>\s+/', '<code>', $str )
```

The regular expression above will match a <code> tag at the beginning of a line (the ^ indicator) and remove all whitespace characters following it (the \s+) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use RegExp, something like this:

```
$trimmed = preg_replace('/(<[^>]*>)\s*/', '\1', $input_string)
```

This will work on ANY html-tag ;)